# Join two tables mysql PHP HTML

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have table as per structure below:

```
Table1:

id    rest_id   rest_naam   rest_min_order    del_charges
----------------------------------------------------------
1         100      Rest1           300           50
2         211      Rest2           400           20
3         322      Rest3           100           60
```

Now i have another table which stores 'Min Order' and 'Delivery Charges' for different sectors / areas

Table2:

```
id    rest_id   del_area     min_od     min_del_chg
----------------------------------------------------
 1      100      Area1        250            20 
 2      100      Area2        200            30
 3      322      Area3        100            50
 4      322      Area4        150            0
```

Now when i will take input from user for his `Area` and `restaurant name` then minimum order and delivery shall be displayed as per the records in `Table2` to the user.

I used query as below:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 where rest_naam = 'User INput' left join Table2 t2 on 
 t2.rest_id=t1.rest_id;
```

With this Delivery charges and Minimum order are getting displayed from both tables. For eg. For Rest=100, user is able to see min order as 300 and 250 when he selects area1.

I want that if Area1 has delivery charges in Table2 then Table1 delivery charges shall not be displayed..

Comment: Have you tried [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)? `SELECT t1.id, t1.rest_id, t1.rest_naam, IFNULL(t2.min_del_chg, t1.del_charges) as delivery_charges FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on 
 t2.rest_id=t1.rest_id WHERE t1.rest_naam = ?`

Comment: with this only 2nd table charges are getting displayed for all areas now..

Comment: I think you should use CASE statement. you should fallow Sean logic but instead of IFNULL try ..., CASE WHEN t2.min_del_chg (condition > 0 or not null whatever)THEN t2.min_del_chg ELSE t1.del_charges END AS deliverry_charges, ....